# header() changes variable value -php

Tags: php, oop

Redirect using `header("location: ")` changes variable value.

In a login form, I used a bool property $isLogged in a class (which was in a class.php file) to check if user is logged in before accessing index.php.

I checked login details in class.php and set $isLogged to true if login details were correct and redirected to index.php using header().

But $isLogged always showed false at index.php.

This is a sample code:

```
<?php
/* class.php */

class SimpleClass {

    private $isLogged = false;

    public function checkLogin() {

        return $this->isLogged;
    }

    public function login() {

        $this->isLogged = true;
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}

$simpleObject = new SimpleClass(); ?>
```

$isLogged is set to true before header call, still checkLogin() returns false at index.php

```
<?php 
/* Index.php */

require_once 'class.php';

// user is not logged in
if(!$simpleObject->checkLogin()) { // The method checkLogin() always returns false

    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

// user is logged in
else
    echo "you've made it!"; ?>
```

Login.php:

```
<?php
    /* Login.php */

    require_once 'class.php';

    // login
    $simpleObject->login(); ?>
```

**NOTE:** The above code gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in browser as both header are called infinitely which happens because checkLogin() returns false.

Comment: You can't just set a class attribute `$this->isLogged` to TRUE to set it as login. because on every request `index.php` is going instantiate a fresh object that will have `$this->isLogged` set to FALSE... **This is the actual cause of infinite loop (thats where session comes into play)**

Comment: DaniyalNasir, Thanks for reply. I suspected index.php is getting a new instance so tried making $isLogged static. But the issue persisted. I guess static variable's value is not shared by all instances of class in php. Will use session, was just trying an alternative.

Comment: Each HTTP request is handled by a new instance of the PHP script. When the script ends it is removed from memory; its variables do not survive. This is not a PHP issue, this is how HTTP has been designed almost 30 years ago (it is a stateless protocol). You need to use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) to make it work as you want.